# Establishing a Node.js Server and ASP.NET MVC 3 client running on different ports

Tags: node.js

I am using sample [Node.js Zoo Chat server](https://gist.github.com/1348247) running at port 2300 and 
only longPoll functionality of its index.html client to show some broadcast info in one of my ASP.NET MVC 3 view page as follows:

Client page script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        longPoll();
    });



    function longPoll(data) {
        if (data && data.messages) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++) {
                var message = data.messages[i];
                $('<p><b>' + message.nickname + ':</b> <span>' + message.text + '</span></p>').hide().prependTo('#messages').slideDown();
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:2300/recv",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                longPoll(data);
            },
            failure: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    }

</script>


<h1>Live Feed</h1>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

The difference is that I don't post messages from a form on client page; rather, it's my MVC webapp (running at port 3000) which periodically sends POST requests to the listening Node.js server via WebRequest. I get those POST request well on server.js but the ajax GET call on client is red on firebug and does not seem to be working. I wonder why?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not the same origin, to be able to send an ajax request, domain and the port must be identical.

Comment: Oh. then how can I capture server.js messages on this client page?

Comment: you can get the data in asp from node server and access it instead.

Comment: @zee check this answer if it was helpul